# How to get a tweetable link via stripe API

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I am trying to get a tweetable link using the stripe relay API. I know how it can be done via dashboard. But I am beginning to think that this is not posible via the stripe API. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tweetable URLs have a pretty defined structure if you looked at them: `https://products.stripe.com/twitter/{{YOUR_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}/products/{{PRODUCT_ID}}`

Comment: Interesting!  Do you know if I can put any account number in there ? To be specific a connected user's Stripe account id.

Comment: If its a standalone account you can put their account number in it, but their account would also have to be connected to Twitter. Also you could not collect an application fee on charges created by Twitter.